# Programmatically creating buttons at different locations

Tags: ios, swift

I programmatically created UIButtons and for them to appear at different locations on the screen. I tried to prevent collisions however they still occur in some instances during testing. The code I'm using is below, any additional logic I have to consider?

```
class PlayViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    let buttonWidth = screenSize.width * 0.15;
    let buttonWidth1 = screenSize.width * 0.20;

    var xPos:[Int] = []
    var yPos:[Int] = []

    for (var i = 0; i<4; i++) {

        var xTemp = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(screenSize.width - buttonWidth1)))
        while xPos.contains((xTemp)) {
            xTemp = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(screenSize.width - buttonWidth1)))

        }

        var yTemp = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(screenSize.height - buttonWidth1)))

        while yPos.contains(yTemp) {
            yTemp = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(screenSize.height - buttonWidth1)))
        }

        let xRand = CGFloat(xTemp)

        var yRand = CGFloat(yTemp)
        if yRand <= buttonWidth1 {
            yRand += buttonWidth1
        }

        let but1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: xRand, y: yRand, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonWidth))
        but1.setTitle(String(i), forState: .Normal)
    but1.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
    but1.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

but1.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    but1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

        self.view.addSubview(but1)

        var x = 0
        while (x <= Int(buttonWidth1)) {
            xTemp += 1
            xPos.append(xTemp)
            x++;
        }
        var y = 0
        while (y <= Int(buttonWidth1)) {
            yTemp += 1
            yPos.append(yTemp)
            y++;
        }
    }
    var g = 0

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

UPDATED CODE

```
var intersection:[CGRect] = []

for (var i = 0; i<x; i++) {

    var xTemp = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(screenSize.width - buttonWidth1)))
    var yTemp = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(screenSize.height - buttonWidth1)))

    if yTemp <= buttonWidth1 {
        yTemp += buttonWidth1
    }

    var rect1 = CGRect(x: xTemp, y: yTemp, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonWidth)
    for element in intersection {
            while CGRectIntersectsRect(rect1, element) {
                xTemp = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(screenSize.width - buttonWidth1)))
                yTemp = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(screenSize.height - buttonWidth1)))

                if yTemp <= buttonWidth1 {
                    yTemp += buttonWidth1
                }

                rect1 = CGRect(x: xTemp, y: yTemp, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonWidth)
            }
    }

    let but1 = UIButton(frame: rect1)
    but1.setTitle(String(i), forState: .Normal)
    but1.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
    but1.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    but1.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    but1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

    self.view.addSubview(but1)

    intersection.append(rect1)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better if you use `CGRectIntersectsRect` to check it the frame of the buttons overlaps.

Comment: I edited my code to include the changes using CGRectIntersectsRect however in some rare instances it still collides.

Comment: I would clean up the code by first generate y and x and then check if the next button will intersect with all other buttons

Comment: Please check the updated code section, I infact did try that however the issue now is they are collide on rare occasions and i think this is because my current code checks if the rect im making collides with the first in the element then second etc, it doesnt go back to check the previous elements in the array, that is what im really stuck on now, any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The first rect1 is not added to elements array. The rect1 created before the for

Comment: Why would I add that to the array? the for loop following is to find a rect that doesnt collide with any of the elements in the array so before I do add the rect1, I'd have to make sure of that. The issue is that if one element intersects with the rect i reassign the x and y locations of the rect and check  the next element if it happens to intersect with the rect, i reassign the x and y points again but the issue is i dont consider that reassigning it could collide it again with the previously checked elements